# ¿Cómo puedo actualizar un DataTable sin perder la paginación de la tabla?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Hola soy nuevo en la programación y necesito si me pueden ayudar con el siguiente inconveniente. Tengo una tabla por booststrap (DataTable) que funciona perfectamente, hasta que inserto un nuevo registro, el cual se realiza por ajax, esto provoca que la paginación por defecto que debe mostrar 10 items, se pierda y muestre todos los registros.

Este es el código ajax:

```
$('#editaCartera').click(function(){
    var recolec = $('#formCartera').serialize();  
    $.ajax({
        url: '../production/lib/procesadores.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: recolec,
        success:function(){            
            Swal.fire({
                title:'Modificado!',
                text: 'El registro fue guardado con éxito ',
                icon:'success'               
            });           
            $('#datatable-responsive').load('tablasMaestras.php #refresh');           
        },
        error: function(){
            $("#modalTipoCartera").modal('hide');
            Swal.fire({
            icon: 'error',
            title: 'Hubo un problema',
            text: 'Intenta nuevamente, de lo contarrio contacta al administrador de sistema'
            }).then((result)=>{ 
                location.reload();
            })
        }
    })
})
```

Este es el código de la tabla:

```
<div id="collapseSrv" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
    <br>
    <div class="x_panel">
        <div class="panel-body" id="refresh">
        
            <table id="datatable" class="table table-hover" style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Código</th>                                                                         
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>Opciones</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody >
                    <?php foreach($tipocartera as $tcartera):
                        $arreglo =  $tcartera['idtipocartera'].','.$tcartera['id_empresa'].','.$tcartera['codigo_tipocartera'].','.$tcartera['nombre_tipocartera'];
                    ?>
                    <tr role="row" class="odd">
                        <td class="sorting_1"><?=$tcartera['idtipocartera']?></td>
                        <td><?=$tcartera['codigo_tipocartera']?></td>
                        <td><?=$tcartera['nombre_tipocartera']?></td>                                                                           
                        <td>
                        <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' id="btnEditar" data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalTipoCartera' onclick="editarCartera('<?=$arreglo?>');"><i class='fa-regular fa-pen-to-square fa-sm'></i></button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" title="Eliminar Tipo de Cargos" onclick="EliminarSuc('<?=$tcartera['idtipocartera']?>.','<?=$tcartera['nombre_tipocartera']?>');"><i class="fa-regular fa-square-minus fa-sm"></i></button>                                                                             
                        </td>                                                                                                                                                       
                    </tr>
                    <?php endforeach ?>                                                                                                                                 
                </tbody>            
            </table>        
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar [row.add()](https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html) método este te permite añadir filas a tu Datatable que ya se encuentra inicializado en tu DOM

digamos que tienes un Datateble ya inicializado pero para que se reflejen nuevos datos tendrías que destruir ese Datatable y tener que inicializarlo nuevamente para que tome los nuevos cambios o las nuevas filas, pero puedes utilizar el metodo de añadir que permite insertar mas filas a tu datatable sin la necesidad de tener que detruir esa instancia de datatable en tu DOM, ejemplo:

```
const table = $('#TuTablaDataTable').DataTable();

function getMasFilas() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '...php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: recolec,
        success: function (response) {
            /* digamos que esto devuelve un array de objetos */
            const datos = JSON.parse(response); 

            /* aquí viene lo interesante, llamar al metodo de add del
            datatable y para esto debes tener en cuenta la cantidad de
             columnas que usas en tu table en tu caso tienes 4 <th> */
            
            $.each(datos, function (_i, e){
                /* Procura que lo que estés pasando al metodo add
                siempre sea un string */
                table.row.add([e.id, e.codigo, e.nombre, e.opciones]).draw(false);

                /* el metodo draw() sirve para dibujar la fila en tu table
                si no lo añades tendrías manualmente actualizar ese elemento DOM
                para reflejar los cambios */
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Si lees la [Documentación](https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html) encontrarás mas ejemplos y métodos similares a este que te pueden servir a resolver tu problema.